# how to add more than one JPanel objects in a single JFrame in swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
public class DisplayData extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5142452052317047239L;
    public DisplayData() throws ErrorCondition, IOException, SAXException {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
        String nonTransientvalue;
        String transientvalue;
        JPanel nonTransientAttriPanel = null;
        JPanel transientAttriPanel=null;

        ReadXml rx=new ReadXml();

        Hashtable<String,String> transientAttributes=rx.getTransientGuiAttributes();
        Hashtable<String,String> nonTransientAttributes=rx.getNonTransientGuiAttributes();
        Iterator<Entry<String,String>> itr=nonTransientAttributes.entrySet().iterator();
            int i = -1; 
            nonTransientAttriPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {

                Entry<String, String> it = itr.next();
                nonTransientvalue = it.getValue();


                constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
                constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
                JLabel labelaccNo = new JLabel(nonTransientvalue);
                JTextField textaccNo = new JTextField(20);
                // add billno
                constraints.gridx = 0;
                constraints.gridy = ++i;
                nonTransientAttriPanel.add(labelaccNo, constraints);
                constraints.gridx = 1;
                nonTransientAttriPanel.add(textaccNo, constraints);
            }


                int j = -1; 
                transientAttriPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                //transientAttriPanel.set
                Iterator<Entry<String,String>> itr1=transientAttributes.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (itr1.hasNext()) {

                    Entry<String, String> it1 = itr1.next();
                    transientvalue = it1.getValue();

                    //GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
                    constraints.insets = new Insets(70, 70, 70, 70);
                    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(transientvalue);
                    JTextField textValue = new JTextField(20);
                    // add billno
                    constraints.gridx = 0;
                    constraints.gridy = ++j;
                    nonTransientAttriPanel.add(nameLabel, constraints);
                    constraints.gridx = 1;
                    nonTransientAttriPanel.add(textValue, constraints);
                }

            f1.setSize(350,300);
            f1.setVisible(true);
            nonTransientAttriPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Non transient Attributes"));
            transientAttriPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Transient Attributes"));
            f1.add(nonTransientAttriPanel);
            f1.add(transientAttriPanel);
            f1.setTitle("Rote Learner Form");
            f1.add(nonTransientAttriPanel);
            f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            // new FetchData().setVisible(true);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set look and feel to the system look and feel
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new DisplayData();
                } catch (ErrorCondition | IOException | SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

this is my class. Where I am using nonTransientAttriPanel and transientAttriPanel these two JPanel objects.
but output I am getting is not as expected. It is displaying all the attributes inside one panel only.

Comment: You always call `nonTransientAttriPanel.add()`, and never `transientAttriPanel.add()`.

Comment: @kiheru Still not working

Comment: What did you change? The `add()` calls in the second loop? Note that you also do not reset the `gridy` constraint before reusing the constraints in that loop.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: Worked with FlowLayout